# Combined question view for Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0

I have accounts on a number of Stack Exchange sites. But I'm a programmer, and therefore lazy. Can I get a site/view that combines questions from **just** the sites I have accounts on?

Seems I only have two options right now:

1. [Stack Exchange Hot Questions](https://stackexchange.com/), which lists questions from all the sites (I only want to see questions from the sites I'm interested in)
2. Visit each site separately.

Can I use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/) to write a query for this? It appears to be only for the trilogy sites.

Answer (score 2):

You can already do this using the existing Tag Sets functionality on Stack Exchange --

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/

> You can enter any tag (or wildcard tag, yep, it supports wildcards) that exists on any site in our network. And once you do, you can choose which site(s) you want to see it on.
>
> [image]
>
> If you’ve ever wanted to narrow down your interests on a site to a few specific topics, or follow a topic across multiple Stack Exchange sites — now you can. Just set up your own tag set, or discover a tag set someone else has already set up!

Comment: Where is this customization sidebar? I'd like to customize my Stack Exchange homepage but I don't see these customization options when I log in.

Comment: @jhocking it got obsoleted by tag sets. I'll change my answer.