# Apply stackexchange.com hot-question site filter in the SE-banner dropdown

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, hot-questions, header

The Super-Cool-SE-Dropdown™ "Hot Questions" tab shows hot questions from all SE sites. Especially as SE grows, I really don't care about most of these. If it was limited to just the sites that I have [selected on stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62828/combined-question-view-for-stack-exchange-sites/65597#65597), that would make it even Super-Cooler.

Comment: @Gnome - I don't see how this is a dupe of that one. We have a combined mini-view in the header, and I'm asking that it only show sites that I signed up for (instead of all of them).

Comment: It's the same feature; though it could be a bug that it doesn't use the same filtering.

Comment: @Gnome - The filtering doesn't work. I tweaked my settings at stackexchange.com and the dropdown still shows everything.

Comment: I confirmed that too; how's this edit?

Comment: @Gnome - that works for me.