# How can I see all my sites?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [See all my questions across all Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74222/see-all-my-questions-across-all-stack-exchange-sites)

I'm a member of 6 or 7 stack exchange sites now. Is there a way to easily access them all? I currently wade through a list of all the sites and say *ah yes, guitar...that's one of mine*.

Bonus Question:
Is there a way to see questions across all the sites to which I belong? I see the option to register an interest in tags across sites, but the setup seems tedious and possibly not worth the trouble.

Comment: Try looking at the accounts tab in your user profile. You can associate your accounts so they show up there (and if you have at least 200 rep on 1 of the sites, you get a 100 rep bonus for associating). As for the bonus question here, this does not exist yet -- I think there's an open feature request for it, though.

Comment: You can use the customizable list described [here, by Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62828/combined-question-view-for-stack-exchange-sites); you have to set it up, but it's easy and you only have to do it once.