How can I get a list of all of my profiles?
Changing my profile's location and clicking "Save and copy changes to all public communities" does not copy my location to all public communities. It only updates the current community. Because of this unaddressed bug from 2018, I have to manually edit each profile. How can I get a list of them all?

https://stackexchange.com/users/2087834/captain-man?tab=accounts

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75702/how-can-i-see-all-my-sites?noredirect=1&lq=1

A list of all your accounts can be found in your Network profile under your accounts tab.
To quickly access your Network profile, click the Network profile button at the top right of your Site profile.
