# Filter on my accounts in StackExchange.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, stackexchange.com

The [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com) page seems to me like a perfect "start page" for starting the day. What I am missing here though is an easy way to see the relevant stackexchange stuff for the sites I have a user account in.

I would like to have a specific filter tab to filter on <sub><sup>(or sort by)</sup></sub>   `my sites`  that lives in all the main categories.

Something like this:

**`hot questions`** `tagged questions` `all sites` `top users`

---

`all` **`my sites`** `popular sites`

> 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My sites is indeed a default tag filter now

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/improved-tag-sets/

As is "my favorite tags" across all sites

Answer (score 0):

This is basically already possible, as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62828/combined-question-view-for-stack-exchange-sites/65597#65597).

Comment: Only partly. I agree that it is a workaround for the `hot questions` category, but I would also want the filtering on `tagged questions`, `all sites` and `top users`, and it would be nice to just have the sites I have accounts in automatically, without having to maintain a separate list of interesting sites. The sites I am interested in are most likely the ones I have accounts in...